# Let $A \subset \mathbb{N}^{\ast}$. Exhibit $(u_n)_{n \geq 1}$ such as $\forall q \in \mathbb{N}^{\ast}$, $\sum_{n\geq 1} u_n^q$ diverges iff $q \in A$

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

I am having difficulties with the following exercise on numerical series :

Let $A \subset \mathbb{N}^{\ast}$. Exhibit a sequence $(u_n)_{n \geq 1} \in \mathbb{C}^{\mathbb{N}^{\ast}}$ such as $\forall q \in \mathbb{N}^{\ast}$, $\sum_{n\geq 1} u_n^q$ diverges iff $q \in A$.

I tried first to study the case of $A$ being a singleton, but I do not have any relevant result yet.

I  have no idea how to go about it ...

How can I proceed?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: For real valued sequence if $\sum u_n^2$ is convergent then $\sum u_n^q$ is convergent for any $q\ge 2.$ So for $A=\{2\}$ there is no sequence $u_n$ satisfying the requirements.  Are you dealing with complex valued sequences ?

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Yes I am dealing with complex sequences, which, I think, allows to exhibit diverging series

Comment: Maybe, given sets $A$ and $B$ where we have sequences, say, $u^{A}$ and $u^{B}$ satisfying that property for $A$ and $B$ respectively, there would be a way to construct a sequence $u^{A \cup B}$ for $A \cup B$? Then, starting from singletons, you would be able to cover every finite set, and then infinite sets with perhaps some Zorn's lemma argument or something similar. But depending on the construction that might not be explicit enough to "exhibit" such sequences... And this is all just hypothetical anyway.

Comment: Found a post on AoPS dealing with this exact problem: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h547818p3174718

Comment: This was the Problem $5$ of the first day of IMC $2013$, a different and more detailed answer compared to the one in AoPS is given on the IMC website: https://www.imc-math.org.uk/?year=2013&item=problems

Comment: @BrunoB thank you very much. This is very helpful, and the solution is very elegant!